# How do I check if a data exist in two sql tables before performing some tasks

Tags: php, sql

names of the tables includes (epin and user)
checks include;

1. if epin exist in tableA(epin) and TableB(user) then echo "epin taken"
2. if epin exist in tableA(epin) only then insert epin to tableb(user)
3. if epin do not exist in tableA then echo "Invalid pint"
   any help please

Comment: Which dialect of SQL?  The procedural language on each database is different...  MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, etc, etc?

Comment: On the face of it, this is a series of really simply queries. What precisely are you having trouble with? Are you trying to optimise it, or run them as part of a transaction to ensure that the epin isn't inserted into table a while you're checking whether it's in table b?

Comment: `echo` is not a SQL operation.

Comment: I'm trying to design a system where users will have to buy an epin after registering. all im trying to do is to make sure they don't bring fake epins.

Answer (score 0):

You can find code with PHP and MySQL.

Suppose we are storing epin search text in below variable.

$searchText = 'searchValue';  // or $searchText = $_GET['searchValue'];

here tableA is epin and TableB is user.

Suppose field name of epin in tableA is epinFieldA and in tableB is epinFieldB.

First point

```
$sql1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as cnt1 FROM epin where epinFieldA = '" .$searchText. "'");
$result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1);

$sql2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as cnt2 FROM user where epinFieldB = '" .$searchText. "'");
$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);
           
if ($result1['cnt1'] > 0 && $result1['cnt2'] > 0) {
echo "epin taken";
}
```

Second point

```
if ($result1['cnt1'] > 0 && $result1['cnt2'] == 0) {
    //insert data query
}
```

Third point

```
if ($result1['cnt1'] == 0) {
    echo "Invalid pint";
}
```